# how to check wether a special character "+" is present in a string using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am using an `if` condition to check if a "+" is present in string. If it is present, it should print some thing, else if "-" is present, it should print some thing else:

```
if ($test_1 =~/^+/)
{
    print OUTFILE1 "Unsigned \n";
}
elsif($test_1 =~/^-/)
{
    print OUTFILE1 "Signed \n";
}
```

Comment: @dan1111: No it's not correct. `/^+/` gives warning `^+ matches null string many times in regex`

Comment: @user3388427: You should put `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the top of your script.

Comment: Whoops!  silly mistake on my part, you are right.

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($test_1 =~/^+/)
```

should be

```
if ($test_1 =~/^\+/)
```

`+` has special meaning in regular expression, if you want to match it as a normal character, you need to escape it.

Comment: Another possibility is `/^[+]/` (which some people find clearer; especially when there are a lot of characters to be escaped).

Comment: @tobyink Yes, there is more than one way to do it :-)

Answer (score 2):

`+` needs to be escaped and you probably don't need start anchor:

```
if ($test_1 =~ /\+/)
{
    print OUTFILE1 "Unsigned \n";
}
elsif ($test_1 =~ /-/)
{
    print OUTFILE1 "Signed \n";
}
```

Comment: but this is not working when i tried to compile this nothing is printing

Comment: What is value of `$test_1`?

Comment: $test_1 will have jus either + or - only

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the function `index()` that is intended to determine the position of a character (*"+" or "-"* in your case) or a substring in a string.

Here you have an example:

```
 ...
if (index($test_1, "+") == 0) { # check if + is in the 0-th position,
  print OUTFILE1 "Unsigned \n"; # that means the 1-st starting from left;
} elsif (index($test_1, "-") == 0) {
  print OUTFILE1 "Signed \n";
}
 ...
```

Comment: -1, this is really not the way to go in Perl.  A regex is a much simpler, more powerful approach.

Comment: Programmer-side Ok, you're right.
Anyway, I don't think so looking it from the intepreter-side. I always considered perl regexes more computationally-complex than perl functions.

Comment: If you are worried about trivial differences in execution time, then perhaps Perl is not the right tool for the job? Perl is about optimizing for development time.

Comment: @dan1111: if I am not worried about execution time, then perhaps jobs in computer science field are not for me.